# CSS form height

Tags: css, forms

I have this input text and input button, I am trying to get them the same height...you can see this at http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/ at the top right....do they look the same height? if not how do I get them to be the same height?

```
<form class="product_search" style="font-size:0px !important;" method="GET" action="<?php echo $pp_url?>/" >
<input name="product_search" id="wpsc_search_autocomplete" class="wpsc_product_search wpsc_live_search_embed .wpsc_live_search" autocomplete="off" style="padding:0px !important; height:23px !important;" />
<input type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="searchBtn" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

and the CSS:

```css
.searchBtn {
    background-color: #FFA18A;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 25.5px;
    width: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Add float:left to input field & button add box-sizing:border-box to them then  set the width accordingly & its will work fine & yes adjust the line height of "Go" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text input has an effective height of 27px, whereas the button has an effective height of 25px.

Try to add these styles:

```
.searchBtn{
  padding: 0;
  height: 27px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make them float back to back and make sure to compensate the border on the input by adding extra height on your button. See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wAgfe/

Answer (score 0):

You have defined:

```
input name="product_search" : height:23px !important
input name="button" : height: 25.5px;
```

Is there any problem to unify both heights?